# Install pinout command in Rpi 1B

Tags: software-installation, terminal

After install RaspiOS lite (2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite) in a Rpi 1B model, I get `command not found` from `pinout` command.

I found [this guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-pinout/) to get pinout command in a Rpi zero:

```
sudo apt install python3-gpiozero
```

Can I use it in a Rpi 1B or is there another way to get the proper command for Rpi 1B model?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install python3-gpiozero
```

This installation works in the 1B model too.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I was able to install the `pinout`-command using `pip3`:

```
sudo pip3 install gpiozero
```